# Как использовать значение в поле Entry для последующего построения графика?

Tags: python, tkinter

К примеру я хочу задавать Q и выводить график по кнопке:

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

root=Tk()
root["bg"] = "lightblue"
root.title("11")
root.geometry("600x300+5+5")

def leftclick(event):
    plt.show()
btn=Button(root, text=u'300..30..3!',
             background="#555",
             foreground="#ccc",
             padx="40",
             pady="30", 
             font="16"
             )
btn.pack()
btn.bind('<Button-1>', leftclick)

entry = IntVar()
Q = Entry(root, textvariable=entry, borderwidth=10, font="16")
Q.pack()

#Q=1500
with open('rr.txt', 'w') as f:
     for i in range(20):
          Q=Q+15*300*(960-650)
          print(Q, file=f)
y=np.loadtxt('rr.txt')
t=np.arange(len(y))*1
plt.figure(facecolor='orange')
plt.plot(t,y)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно вывести значение хранящиеся в  `Entry`, то можете в функции `leftclick`написать `a = q.get()`.

Пример кода если конечно это вам и нужно было в результате:

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

root=Tk()
root["bg"] = "lightblue"
root.title("11")
root.geometry("600x300+5+5")

def leftclick(event):
    a = int(q.get())
    with open('rr.txt', 'w') as f:
         for i in range(20):
              a=a+15*300*(960-650)
              print(a, file=f)
    y = np.loadtxt('rr.txt')
    t = np.arange(len(y)) * 1
    plt.figure(facecolor='orange')
    plt.plot(t, y)
    plt.show()


btn = Button(root, text=u'300..30..3!',
                 background="#555",
                 foreground="#ccc",
                 padx="40",
                 pady="30",
                 font="16"
                 )
btn.pack()
btn.bind('<Button-1>', leftclick)

entry = IntVar()

q = Entry(root, textvariable=entry, borderwidth=10, font="16")
q.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Так же используйте маленькие буквы для обозначение переменных как по правилам [PEP8](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html#id28) Заглавные буквы используются при написания названия `class`

Comment: Да, всё верно, но именно
`a=a+15*300*(960-650)
print(a, file=f)`
Следующая к предыдущей добавляется.

Comment: @LaGaSiO подправил.